# Showing background image in IE8

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8, background-image

My background images aren't showing in IE8:

```
<tr>
    <td height="11"></td>
    <td height="11"></td>
    <td height="11" background="images/lgin-bg-blnk.jpg">kjsdfk</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What kind of Qs is this...!!!!
What is the exact problem....

Comment: I've applied code formatting; that might help.

Comment: my backgrond images are not showing in ie8

Comment: Are they visible in all other browsers..?

Answer (score 0):

`<td height="11" background="images/lgin-bg-blnk.jpg">kjsdfk</td>`

presuming from the title you want a background image it should be in a `style` attribute like below, or even better in an external stylesheet..

`<td height="11" style="background: url(images/lgin-bg-blnk.jpg);">kjsdfk</td>`

---

`background` is not a valid HTML attribute for a `TD`, though it was a non-standard property that was supported by older Netscape and IE browsers [see: TH/TD definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TD)

> - id, class (document-wide identifiers)
> - lang (language information),
> - dir (text direction)
> - title (element title)
> - style (inline style information )
> - onclick, ondblclick, onmousedown,
>     onmouseup, onmouseover, onmousemove,
>     onmouseout, onkeypress, onkeydown,
>     onkeyup (intrinsic events )
> - bgcolor (background color)
> - align,
>     char, charoff, valign (cell alignment)

---

**Added**: reference for quotes/no quotes : [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri)

Comment: You have double quotes inside your double quotes, which won't work. Make the ones inside the parenthesis single quotes instead.

Comment: oops typo, curse of the copy/paste of the original code ;) thanks @Dori - I removed the internal quotes instead, though single ones would do too.. I usually write them without quotes due to older browser problems

Answer (score 0):

`background` is not a valid attribute for a `<td>` element. Try changing it to an inline CSS style:

`<td height=11 style="background:url('images/lgin-bg-blnk.jpg')">...</td>`

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the width also.

```
<td height="11" width="" style="background: url(images/lgin-bg-blnk.jpg);">kjsdfk</td>
```